# spring security database login error, error object is not null

Tags: spring-security

I am new to spring security.
I tried to implement the following example.
https://mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

I used the url in both google chrome and firefox:

This is my database:

[image]
Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: properly post the error msg

Comment: @jadeite above program works fine for me. please share the error message